# Proving a series is greater than zero

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wish to prove that an equation is greater than zero.

Let $\Delta_0=(2n+1)+\sum\limits_{v=1}^{log_2((n+1)^2)}\frac{g(2v,2n+1,(n+1)^2)}{2v+1}-\sum\limits_{v=1}^{log_2((n+1)^2)}\frac{f(2v-1,2n+1,(n+1)^2)}{2v}$

where $g(2v,2n+1,(n+1)^2)=\sum\limits_{a=2}^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{2v-1}}}\sum\limits_{b=2}^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{a*2^{2v-2}}}...\sum\limits_{z=2}^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{a*b*...*2}}(\lfloor \frac{2n+1}{ab...z} \rfloor)$

and  $f(2v-1,2n+1,(n+1)^2)=\sum\limits_{a=2}^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^{2v-2}}}\sum\limits_{b=2}^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{a*2^{2v-3}}}...\sum\limits_{z=2}^{\frac{(n+1)^2}{a*b*...*2}}(\lfloor \frac{2n+1}{ab...z} \rfloor-1)$

Note: in both $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$ $x$ is the number of series. Example: if $x=1$ then it would only be the fraction $\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{a}\rfloor$ if x=2, $\lfloor\frac{2n+1}{ab}\rfloor$ etc.

I suspect that for all large $n$, $\Delta_0>>0$ but am unable to prove it. Is there some better way to simplify or create an even simpler lower bound approximation that is greater than zero?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem?

Comment: Although it is hard to tell, the above equations are part of an attempt of mine to prove Legendre's conjecture. While I doubt my proof is rigorous it is a fun project/learning experience.